# What effect does the topological term have in string theory?

Tags: string-theory, topological-field-theory

In string theory we may have an Polyakov action like:

$$S=\int\sqrt{g} (g^{ij}\eta_{\mu\nu}\partial_i X^\mu \partial_j X^\nu + \kappa R) d\sigma^2$$

The curvature $R$ gives a topological term (it is the curvature in terms of the world-sheet metric $g$). When integrating over a world sheet it seems to give a factor of $\lambda=e^{\kappa}$ for each additional hole. In particular it seems to give a factor of $\lambda^{1-n}$ where $n$ is the number of holes.

Is this correct?

Does this mean $\lambda$ gives an amplitude for a string to split? Is $\kappa$ an independent variable or can it be absorbed into other constants?

If it is similar to the fine structure constant, it would mean that if string perturbation theory is asymptotic then the it would begin to diverge after about $\lambda$ terms. Does this seem right?

Comment: Why would this factor produce $\mathrm{e}^\kappa$ "for each additional hole"? By Gauß-Bonnet, $\int\sqrt{g} R$ is just the Euler characteristic of the worldsheet and your $\kappa$ is just a constant, right? What does this have to do with the "amplitude for a string to split"? What does that even mean - string theory amplitudes are between in- and out-states of the (S)CFT that lives on the worldsheet, not in terms of something physical happening to the string in the classical sense.

Comment: Huh? Euler characteristic counts the hole in a surface.  When a string splits in two and rejoins this makes a hole in the world-sheet. Nothing complicated. We sum over worldsheets with 1,2,3,.. holes. Amplitudes calculated with path integrals over $e^{iS}$ with vertex insertions.

Comment: 1. The Euler characteristic of a closed oriented worldsheet is $2-2g$, where $g$ is the "number of holes", i.e the genus, so your factor should be something else. 2. Ordinary string scattering amplitudes are for the *insertions* - representing the in and out states - and are a sum over worldsheet topologies. I do not understand how this is supposed to be related to "an amplitude for a string to split".

Comment: In a normal Feynman diagram we have factors of the (square root) of the fine structure constant at the vertices. This is commonly called the amplitude for a particle to emit another particle. This is common parlance. Likewise for a worldsheet one could interpret a world-sheet with holes in terms of feynman graphs with vertices. I fail to see the difficulty here.